# Does @supports 'not' keyword work if @supports is not supported?

Tags: css

#### Some confusion.

I would like to use @supports more often but... I'm not about how the browser sees it. I hope you can clarify, and thank you if you can.

How does a browser compute @support 'not' keyword if it itself does not understand @supports. Does it ignore the not block? Should I 'not' bother with @supports 'not' keyword and just provide over-ride code.. or even provide both methods of fall-back in the not support block and outside of it.

Many thanks,
I'm really sorry that this question is hard to read but there is no easy way of saying this.

Comment: If `@supports` is not supported, the whole `@supports` block is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If a browser doesn't understand @supports, then everything between the @supports token and the next {} pair is considered foreign and it doesn't even try to interpret it at all (so it has no idea the "not" is there or what it's supposed to mean). It just discards the entire at-rule and moves on, the moment it encounters the @supports token.

This is a good thing, because then you don't have to worry about browsers that don't understand @supports trying to interpret it and behaving unexpectedly as a result. You can assume that any browser that doesn't understand @supports will always ignore it, and write accordingly.

If you need to support browsers that don't understand this at-rule, I would avoid using it. It is only really useful if all the browsers you are targeting do support it, or if you are using it to guard a feature that's only supported by browsers that do understand it anyway.

Comment: Wonderful so I should consider @supports as a sort of html 5+ tool for maybe the odd property here and there, In practice then, the better option is the classic override method.